# Google cloud bucket through Storage account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, blobstorage

New to GCP and looking for some help on how to access the project storage bucket using a Service Account. Can Storage accounts not be accessed via google console like how Azure blob storages are accessed?

Comment: What is the question and problem? Yes, you can access your cloud storage account in the Google Cloud Console (Web) GUI. Azure has several methods of accessing storage, Google was well. Edit your question to show the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks John for your reply; So I have a Service account key .json file provided by the Admin and I need to use this to access the project cloud bucket. I want to know what are the ways to do this?

Comment: If your credentials are a service account, then you can use the CLI **gsutil**. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil The Google Cloud Console Web GUI requires a user account or federated credentials for authorization. If you are just getting started with Google Cloud, I recommend using Google Qwiklabs to learn the basics. https://www.qwiklabs.com/